# Can't use Ajax to Send/Retrieve variables To/From Server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Quite confused with the answers in the StackOverFlow and the whole Internet! I have some problems which seem easy but can't solve them since some days!

In my scenario (Online Booking System), I want to take the entered values in the FORM (Starting Time and Duration of the reservation) and send it to the SERVER (PHP); In the PHP function I will check if they are valid (some SQL queries and PHP functions); Then I'll retrieve the result back to the JQuery (as json encoded array);

The current snippets are as follow:

My HTML form:

```
<FORM ACTION="add.php" METHOD="post" ID="submitform">
    <INPUT type="text" cols="50" id="starting_time" NAME="starting_time" PLACEHOLDER="Starting Time" /><br />
    <INPUT type="text" id="duration" NAME="duration" PLACEHOLDER="Duration"/><br />
    <P>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint"></SPAN></P>
    <INPUT type="button" value='Add Reservation' id="button" />
    <DIV ID="ajaxfield"></DIV>
</FORM>
```

My JQuery and AJAX codes:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>

 $(function(){

 $('#button').click(function(){
 $('#container').append('<img src= "ajax-loader.gif" alt="Currently loading" id="loading" />');

 var str = $('#submitform').serializeArray();

  $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: 'availability.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType:'JSON',
        data: $str,
        success: function(response){
                resultObj = eval (response);
                alert( resultObj ); 
                }
             });
        });
     });

 </script>
```

My PHP:

```
<?php

  header('Content-Type: application/json');

  $starting_time = $_POST['starting_time'];
  $duration = $_POST['duration'];

  availability($starting_time, $duration);

  function availability($starting_time, $duration) { 
        THE FUNCTION STUFF
    }
   echo json_encode( $arr );
  }

 ?>
```

Now, the problem is first of all this is not working and the script is being stuck on the loader.gif!

And second how can I manipulate the json array from PHP to do some stuff, like enabling the submit button and/or suggesting a duration which works for the user.

PS: And of course, IN the final scenario I want to check these things instantly and before user presses the submission button.

Thanks!

---

**EDIT**

Some part of my problem is solved by the notes from answers, this is the modified code (till now):

```
    var str = $('#submitform').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: 'availability.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType:'JSON',
        data: str,
        success: function(data){
                alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, "\t"))

        }
    });
```

Now, obviously I could alert the JSON returned from the PHP function; I'll just need to modify it to manipulate for my purposes.

Comment: `var str = $('#submitform').serializeArray();` then later you use `data: $str` (note the dollar sign). The two are not equivalent. You also want to just be using `.serialize()` if you want to pass it as data, that's what it's for. Also if you specify the `json` dataType for the AJAX call your `response` variable will already be the object or array, it's **not** a JSON string, that means no calling `resultObj = eval(response)`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all... I'll try to teach you a bit of fishing instead of just giving you a fish...

You say that your code is just stuck on the loader.gif... you've been several days stuck so I supose you had time enough to detect where your code stops, to detect if there is any error on your javascript code or if your client code execution reachs your server code.

The only info you give us saying that it's stuck on the loader is that this line of code:

```
$('#container').append('<img src= "ajax-loader.gif" alt="Currently loading" id="loading" />');
```

Has been executed.

Well... and now?
Ok, you can check things like the following:

1. Check if str contains what you expect it to contains.
2. Check if execution reachs availability.php
3. Check what $str contains (is the data you're trying to pass to your server)

Surely during those checkings you'll see some light through your doubts and you'll be able to post here a more detailed question.